# How to see API requests details?

Tags: api, limits

Is it possible to see which classes(or anything else) used API requests?

Out org allows only 15k API requests per 24 hours, but somehow we managed to go over the limit. After googling I only found that the only "workaround" is to contact salesforce and ask for temporary increase of this limitation.

System overview page API requests:

[image: System overview]

API Calls Made Within Last 7 Days report:

[image: Last 7 days report]

Is there a way to get details of those 15k calls to see where were they made?

Comment: what was the reason of downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Event Log Files, which is part of the Winter '15 release:
http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_security_elf.htm#topic-title

As far as I know there's no solution other than this, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: the problem is that because of this limit I can't login to Workbench, open Developer console or save/run anything from MavensMate

Comment: Ah fair enough. You may indeed just want to contact Salesforce, their support will usually quickly grant your request without any additional costs. If the issue persists you could look into using an app from the AppExchange for logging (i.e. _S4G Logger_) or write your own logger using a custom object. Someone else might have a more satisfying answer though. :-)